# Laravel Cache in Process

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with caching in queue. I want to cache a simple api response so I did this:

Controller:

```
CachingProcess::dispatch()->onQueue('system');

        return Cache::rememberForever('cache_data', function() {
            $query = SomeModel::get();

            return new SomeCollection($query);
        });
```

So the process looks like:

```
public function handle()
    {
        Cache::rememberForever('cache_data', function() {
            $query= SomeModel::get();

            return new SomeCollection($query);
        });
    }
```

And in failed_jobs is always returning an error

> Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in
> C:\Users/myuser\Projects\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\FileStore.php:77

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: which namespace you used for `Cache`?

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

Comment: could you `dd` of the `collection` result  and make sure it is not null or giving any error

Comment: I'm going to guess there's something in SomeModel or SomeCollection that has a Closure that can't be serialized. There are quite a few questions on SO about this error with Laravel Queues, but they all relate to trying to save `$request`, which cannot be serialized.

Comment: Well interisting thing is that I'm not getting this error anymore, but it's not caching as expected anyway